# HTMLAnchor element download not working in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I can't get the HTMLAnchor element's download property to work under TypeScript.
I'm using the following code:

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);
    element.target = '_blank';
    element.mimeType = "attachment/csv";
    element.download = 'Report.csv';  /* #debug 030314  this line fails */
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
```

It seems that the download property isn't supported in TypeScript. Is there a work-around, that adds the .csv suffix to the file?
- Is it possible to bypass TypeScript and call the Javascript code directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily add it yourself:

```
// Tell TypeScript about it
interface HTMLAnchorElement{
    download:string;    
}


var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);
    element.target = '_blank';
    element.mimeType = "attachment/csv";
    element.download = 'Report.csv';  /* No error on this line anymore */
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
```

Answer (score 8):

The `download` attribute hasn't been [widely](http://caniuse.com/download) accepted yet, so they haven't implemented it.

You can always fall back to the completely supported `setAttribute`:

```
element.setAttribute("download", "Report.csv");
```